How can I correctly creat this shorcut file with its arguments?
I want to create a shortcut file to a PDF document with arguments, so that when I double click it on Explorer, it will open the pdf file in my default PDF viewer at the page specified.
I can create such a shortcut in Explorer, by right clicking the PDF file then:

Clicking on "Create Shortcut"
Opening the properties dialog for the file
Replacing the entire string present in the target field with  PDFXEdit /a page=87 "C:\temp\sample.pdf"

I would like a PowerShell means of doing the above, I tried:
set-shorcut -Path 'c:\temp\sample.pdf' -Arguments 'PDFXEdit /a page=87' | get-shortcut

WindowStyle : 1
Path        : C:\temp\sample.lnk
IconPath    : ,0
Hotkey      :
Arguments   : PDFXEdit /a page=87
Target      : C:\temp\sample.pdf

The shortcut does get created but when I look at the target field for the shortcuts file's properties dialog, its value is:
"C:\temp\sample.pdf" PDFXEdit /a page=87

and executing it does open the file with the default pdf programme but not at page 87.
It seems that the expected value is PDFXEdit /a page=87 "C:\temp\sample.pdf" yet I cant seem to do this in PowerShell.
Is it not possible for .lnk files, to just attempt to pass a file path and some arbitrary argument to the current 'open with...' pdf programme??
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code for set-shortcut is:
function Set-Shortcut{
param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
  [String]$Path = $pwd,

  [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ValueFromPipeline)]
  [String]
  $Target,

  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
  [String]
  $Arguments,

  [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
  [String]
  $IconPath
)
process{
    if (-not(get-item -path $path).PSIsContainer){Write-Error 'Only directories allowed as destination Path' -ErrorAction Stop}
    $path = join-path -path $path -ChildPath ((get-item -path $target).BaseName + '.lnk')
    $WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($Path)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $Target

    Switch ($PSBoundParameters.keys){
    'Arguments' {$Shortcut.Arguments = $Arguments}
    'IconPath'  {$Shortcut.IconLocation = $IconPath}
    }
    $Shortcut.Save()
    return (Get-Item $Path)
    }
}


When you manually create the shortcut you then edit it to completely change what the shortcut points to. Specifically you change it to point at the PDFXEdit application, with arguments including the path to the file and page number. So when you create the shortcut in PowerShell you would still want to replicate those changes.
set-shorcut -Path PDFXEdit -Arguments '/a page=87 "c:\temp\sample.pdf"' | get-shortcut


Since you are running WShell from Powershell it may be simpler to use the VBS format and double click that to build a shortcut.lnk. The Microsoft example is
         set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
         strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
         set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\Shortcut Script.lnk")
         oShellLink.TargetPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
         oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
         oShellLink.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+F"
         oShellLink.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 0"
         oShellLink.Description = "Shortcut Script"
         oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop
         oShellLink.Save

Which could be adapted to take arguments too or run via CMD parameters
So in this case, I have allowed for filenames with spaces (Windows will discard if not required), such that the format could be,
MakeLink.vbs
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments 'unused but consider could be objArgs(0)=My.lnk (1)=My.exe (2)="MyTarget args"
Dim LnkName
LnkName = "My Shortcut.lnk"
exeName = "C:\path to\pdfxedit.exe"

With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut(LnkName)
 .TargetPath = chr(34) & exeName & chr(34)
 .Arguments = "/A page=87 "& chr(34) &"c:\temp\sample.pdf"& chr(34)
 .IconLocation = exeName & ",0"
 .Description = "Click Me"
 .WindowStyle = 1 'Note 1 = normal 3 = maximise 7 = minimise
 .WorkingDirectory = "c:\temp\"
 .Save
End With


NOTE that each time you add a shortcut it consumes usually a minimal 4 KB of disk space (see "Size on Disk" properties). With a large number of such entries that may consume an undesirable chunk of disk space.
Thus there are potentially better ways to call a block of known commands to open file by page number, such as select given name from a list, array, or pass the page number at time of calling.
In Windows you can use MS Edge to view PDF (or ePub) fairly rapidly at a given page in its own full height half screen window. Again that can be called with a sortcut or any one of other convieninces such as "SendTo" or a choice of "which page" to start with.

